# Javascript regex match every two groups of numbers > letters and numbers ?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Trying to create a regex to:

•   To get any number or multiple numbers first provided there’s no spacing

•   Then select a group of letters and numbers after any space. (Numbers optional)

This is currently working only when the groups of letters and numbers ends in a number

```
This is my regex - /(\b\d+\s+([a-z+d])+\d+\b)|(\b\d+\s+([a-z+d])+\b)/ig
```

This is my test string:

```
5 CF377A 
4
0 0CF377
```

At the moment its just currently selecting

```
0 0CF377
```

The result I need is

```
5 CF377A 
0 CF377
```

Link to my regular expression - [Regex expression](https://regex101.com/r/zYZK67/2)

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This captures the visible use-cases you've provided, but I'm not sure it passes all the requirements of your written description:

```
(^\d+ +[a-z0-9]+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zYZK67/4)